# how to setup the opacity in the stencil brush mode in blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I'm trying to make the projection painting of the face texture over the old one,but the new image texture is not transparent enough and I'm not able to see behind. How can I make it more transparent ? thanks...

[image: 1]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look in the properties panel under the tool and see the panel 'Display' and open that, and there you can set the stencil brush opacity and toggle it to disappear on stroke.
[image]

Comment: thanks. is there some shortcuts to rotate,scale,transform the texture ? I see that I can modify the angle,the size etc but I find that using that method is not comfortable.

Comment: Yes, explore what happens with RMB to to move, Shift-RMB to Scale, and Ctrl-RMB to rotate.

Answer (score 2):

Blender 2.83 - moved under **>Cursor >Texture Opacity**..
or
Under **Overlays**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Blender v2.83**

When you are in `Texture Paint` mode in the `3D Viewport` and are using a texture as a stencil for the Draw tool, you can adjust the opacity of the image which displays when you use the tool. This is found under the `Cursor` setting, detailed below.

---

**Using a texture as a stencil**

1. Open the `3D Viewport` and set the mode to `Texture Paint`.
2. Select the Draw tool.
3. Open the `Properties Editor` -> select the `Active Tool and Workspace settings` tab -> `Brush Settings` -> `Texture` -> and change the following :

[] set the texture, or locate an image for the texture here, 
          [] set the dropdown for `Mapping` -> to "Stencil"

---

**Changing the visual opacity of the stencil**

There are 2 locations (as of Blender v2.83) to change the visual opacity of the stencil (note, this is different from the strength of the tool, and this is *also* different from the `Stencil Mask`)

Select the Draw tool in the `3D Viewport` while in `Texture Paint` mode.
Then find the setting at either of the following locations:

1. `3D Viewport` -> `Sidebar` -> `Tool` tab -> `Brush Settings` panel -> `Cursor` -> `Texture Opacity`
2. `Properties Editor` -> `Active Tool and Workspace settings` tab -> `Brush Settings` -> `Cursor` -> `Texture Opacity`

[image: Fully Opaque Stencil for Draw Tool][image]

---

**Word of caution :**

The following setting will not affect the opacity of the *Stencil which displays under your cursor* when using a Texture Stencil as described above.

The following setting affects the `Stencil Mask` opacity:

- `3D Viewport` -> `Texture Paint mode` -> `Show Overlays` (just below the Header's Menu) -> dropdown options
  -> `Texture Paint` -> `Stencil Opacity`

The `Stencil Mask` can be toggled on in the Overlay options via :

- `3D Viewport` -> `Texture Paint mode` -> `Header` Menu -> `Masking` Dropdown -> `Stencil Mask` checkbox.

The following animated gif demonstrates the difference between the `Cursor`'s `Texture Opacity` setting (the answer I gave above to Marietto's question),
from the settings affecting the `Stencil Mask`:

https://i.imgur.com/eT5HD5u.gif